# Modify Number Counter with Comma

Tags: javascript

I realize there are a bunch of SO posts about a number counter and several about adding commas to number strings. I've looked through as many as I can find, and through trial and error, I was able to make a number counter work on a test page (as well as adding a function that triggers the counter when a user scrolls to a certain div on the page--because of that, you have to scroll before the numbers appear... which is fine for our intended use).

Here's the tricky part: I cannot add JQuery to the site I'm working on because I have limited file upload access (limited to docs, PDFs, and images). I think it currently references Jquery, but from what I can tell, it's v.1.1, which seems super old...

I've tried every solution I could find on SO and JSFiddle for the last week, and the code referenced below is the only one with working animation, but it doesn't add a comma between the hundredths and thousandths place.

I'm primarily a Photographer/Designer, so I'm a Javascript noob. I'm hoping someone can help. I just need to add commas in between the hundredths and thousandths place on this number counter.

**Test Page:**

http://www.DenverRescueMission.org/test

**Notes:**

- .toLocaleString() - Doesn't appear to work, but I might be creating
  syntax errors by adding it in the wrong place.
- I realize this code is probably much clunkier than necessary, but
  it's the only version I could find that works on our site.
- I will gladly try any suggestions for a cleaner code, but I only know
  that the code below actually works.
- The CSS for the styles on the numbers are incomplete, but workable
  for testing.

**JS:**

```
! function(t) {
t.fn.countTo = function(e) {
    return e = e || {}, t(this).each(function() {
        var o = t.extend({}, t.fn.countTo.defaults, {
                from: t(this).data("from"),
                to: t(this).data("to"),
                speed: t(this).data("speed"),
                refreshInterval: t(this).data("refresh-interval"),
                decimals: t(this).data("decimals")
            }, e),
            n = Math.ceil(o.speed / o.refreshInterval),
            a = (o.to - o.from) / n,
            r = this,
            l = t(this),
            i = 0,
            c = o.from,
            s = l.data("countTo") || {};

        function f(t) {
            var e = o.formatter.call(r, t, o);
            l.html(e)
        }
        l.data("countTo", s), s.interval && clearInterval(s.interval), 
s.interval = setInterval(function() {
            i++, f(c += a), "function" == typeof o.onUpdate && 
o.onUpdate.call(r, c);
            i >= n && (l.removeData("countTo"), clearInterval(s.interval), c 
= o.to, "function" == typeof o.onComplete && o.onComplete.call(r, c))
        }, o.refreshInterval), f(c)
    })
}, t.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,
    to: 0,
    speed: 1e3,
    refreshInterval: 100,
    decimals: 0,
    formatter: function(t, e) {
        return t.toLocaleString('en-US').toFixed(e.decimals)
    },
    onUpdate: null,
    onComplete: null
}
}(jQuery), jQuery(function(t) {
t(".count-number").data("countToOptions", {
        formatter: function(t, e) {
            return t.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
        }
    }

    function commas(str) {
        return (str + "").replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
}), t(window).scroll(function() {
var e = t("#stats").offset().top,
    o = t("#stats").outerHeight(),
    n = t(window).height(),
    a = t(this).scrollTop();
if (console.log(e - n, a), a > e + o - n) {
    console.log("reach"), t(".timer").each(function(e) {
        var o = t(this);
        e = t.extend({}, e || {}, o.data("countToOptions") || {}), 
o.countTo(e)
    }), t(window).off("scroll")
}
})
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class="timer stats-number" data-to="907125" data-speed="1500"></p>
```

Comment: Why don't you just reference jquery by cdn?
` <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     `

Comment: I also tried an external reference to a jQuery file, but it did not work either. It's a goofy website we're going to redo eventually. If I do reference another jQuery file, won't I need to rewrite the counter code anyway? (Again, JavaScript noob here...)

Comment: Okay, different problem:

Comment: Okay, different problem: The code here is working: https://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/pen/rcfsJ But, runs immediately. I had modified this code to make the counter wait until the user scrolled to a <div>. Now that the commas are working, how do I make the following code wait until a user scrolls to a <div> with a specific ID?

Comment: I think my scroll modification broke the original comma functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the class that was applying the commas.

The class was "count-number".

I knew it would end up being a silly mistake, just could not see it.